# How are buttons drawn in android after the first tap?

Tags: android, internals

I'm trying to draw a rotated layout in Android (because my app has to run in Landscape mode for reasons outside my control and I want to draw the widgets rotated 90 degrees so they'll look right when the device is in portrait mode). I've gotten it to work except for button highlights--they are not drawing correctly (one button's highlight will sometimes draw inside of two buttons). I tried to debug this by setting a breakpoint in Button.draw(), but to my surprise it is only called twice: once for the button in its normal state, and once for the first time the highlight is drawn. From then on, it must be cached. Where does the drawing actually occur? I tried calling setDrawingCacheEnabled(false) on the button but that didn't change its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is no caching, the problem comes from the fact that you probably don't rotate the dirty region when an invalidate() call happens.